# How can I implement user interactions in p5.js? I know that p5 doesn't support interactions natively but is there was a way I could write my own?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, web-services, user-interface, p5.js

So I am trying to implement a data visualization tool written in p5.js (since it provides a canvas for me to draw my visualization). The data type is a javascript object with properties: name and an array of children and the visualization is a simple recursive tree where each branch represents a node. The main drawing function has been written and tested.

I know that p5 does not have any interactions out of the box hence I face a hurdle when I am trying to write user interactions, mainly, I have in mind that when the user hovers the mouse over a node (i.e. a branch) it should display the name of the code, and secondly, when a user clicks on node, a new tree should be drawn by taking the clicked node as the root (and possibly reverting back to the original by clicking the root of the new tree).

I will refrain from posting my code since it is a group project and the other group members won't appreciate me posting the code. So I am not looking so much for concrete code but mostly for ideas and/or algorithms to implement them.

I am looking forward to suggestions on how to implement such a functionality. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

P5.js does support user input. Check out the **events** section of [the reference](https://p5js.org/reference/).

For example here is a sketch that shows a green circle that turns red when you mouse over it:

```
function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400);
}

function draw() {
  if(dist(mouseX, mouseY, width/2, height/2) < 100){
        fill(255, 0, 0);
    }
    else{
        fill(0, 255, 0);    
    }

    background(32);
    ellipse(width/2, height/2, 200);
}
```

Shameless self-promotion: [here](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/processing/input) is a tutorial on user input. It's written for Processing, but many of the same principles apply to P5.js.

If you're still having trouble, please ask a more specific question in a new post. You shouldn't be posting your full program anyway- instead, please try to narrow your problem down to a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

Its quite simple actually. If you have an object storing all the nodes
then loop to display the nodes and interactions by checking if `mouseX` and `mouseY` are above the node.
If your node is a `rect()` it should be easy

```
void node = //node here       
if(mouseX>node.x&&mouseX<node.x+node.width&&mouseY>node.y&&mouseY<node.y+node.height){
   //Display information about node when mouse hovers
}
//Later
mouseClicked(){
    if(mouseX>node.x&&mouseX<node.x+node.width&&mouseY>node.y&&mouseY<node.y+node.height){
       //When clicked on node
    }
}
```

I suggest checking out some of the mouse examples at the site https://processing.org/examples/

Comment: this would indeed work if I stored coordinates of the nodes, which I am not currently doing! so could I make an additional array to store the coordinates?

Comment: you wouldnt need to store the coordinates of the nodes in the node itself. However you are drawing the nodes you can use this principle here.
If you are using a `for()` then just replace the `node.x` to your node's math of it's X